# Spring display error message

Tags: java, spring, exception

I'm using spring 4.1.3.RELEASE

I have the following form:

```
<form method="GET">
    <label for="employeeId">Id:</label> 
    <form:input path="empId" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The submit button send a request which is going to be handled by the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{empId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getEmployeeById(@PathVariable @ModelAttribute String empId, BindException binding, Model model){
    try{
        model.addAttribute("employee", employeeDAO.getEmployeeById(Integer.valueOf(empId)));
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException ex) {
        binding.reject("405", "Employee not found");
    }
    return "employeesList";
}
```

The `employeeDAO.getEmployeeById` method throws the `EmptyResultDataAccessException` if there's no an employee with such an id. I need to display an error message if the exception was thrown. The code I provided doesn't work. It throws an expcetion:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be declared immediately after the model attribute, the @RequestBody or the @RequestPart arguments to which they apply: public java.lang.String com.badmitrii.EmployeeListController.getEmployeeById(java.lang.String,org.springframework.validation.BindException,org.springframework.ui.Model)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ErrorsMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(ErrorsMethodArgumentResolver.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

I tried to remove `@ModelAttribute`, but the same expcetion was occured. How to resolve the issue? Maybe there's a better way to do that rather than trying to handle an exception with the `BindingException` class?

Comment: Your controller is flawed, you aren't using a model so `@ModelAttribute` isn't helpful here, `@PathVariable` is only for an URL containing the id, you are submitting it as a request parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As per the exception detail ,you should remove `@PathVariable`,use only `@ModelAttribute`.

Because as per exception the `BindingResult` can only be added after `@RequestBody,@ModelAttribute. or @RequestPart`,and here you are using combination of two annotation,(`@PathVariable && @ModelAttribute`)

For more info:- see [Source Code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.web/3.2.5/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/ErrorsMethodArgumentResolver.java) for this error.

PS:- After above change,you may be getting 400.Then you will have to change the `empId` sending way from JSP.